# Java Generics Bound mismatch

Tags: java, sorting, generics, mismatch

Here is a implementation of a generic search algorithm:

The interface:

```
public interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    int compare(T arg); 
}
```

CompareSort.java

```
public abstract class CompareSort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

protected boolean less(T v, T w) {
    return (v.compare(w) < 0);
}

protected void swap(T[] args, int i, int j) {
        T swap = args[i];
        args[i] = args[j];
        args[j] = swap;
}

public abstract void sort(T[] args);
```

}

One of the algorithm:

```
public class SelectionSort <T extends Comparable<T>> extends CompareSort<T>  {

@Override
public void sort(T[] args) {
    int N = args.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (less(args[j], args[min])) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        swap(args, i, min);
    }
}
```

}

And finally a main method to sort Strings.

```
public class StringSorter {
    public static  <T extends Comparable<T>> void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) { 
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
            String str = s.nextLine(); 
            list.add(str);
            i++;
        }
        String[] a = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

        // Create a sort object, use it on a, and print the sorted array.
        SelectionSort<String> selection = new SelectionSort<String>();
        selection.sort(a);
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
SelectionSort<String> selection = new SelectionSort<String>();
```

> Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter (T extends Comparable(T)) of the type SelectionSort(T)

(box brackets = curved brackets)

Where is the problem? I can not figure it out...
the generic parameter T is extended as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating your own `Comparable`, which `String` **does not** implement, use Java's `java.lang.Comparable`, which `String` **does** implement.

Comment: +1 *and* never create classes with the same name as classes from the JDK! There's no better way to create confusion for humans.